# How do I get a sql query for a database in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do I get the query for a dump of an entire MySQL database in PHP? I am planning to then dump it into a .sql file.

Comment: Why use PHP to do this?  Am I missing something, or is this not what mysqldump is there for?

Comment: why do you want to access it from PHP. Usually you will manually execute it.

Comment: Because its part of a PHP Web Application where it gives you a backup of the script's tables from inside the ACP.

Comment: It can also be useful for backing up an application on cron without having to use another language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single "query" (unless the database is structurally simple).  What you are asking for is a maintenance operation which is done with the specialized utility [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-mysqldump.html).

Answer (score 1):

i dont think you can do like a mysql_query("BACKUP NOW");
instead look here:

http://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php

http://www.noupe.com/how-tos/10-ways-to-automatically-manually-backup-mysql-database.html